# Photoemission - A surface process?

Tags: condensed-matter, electrons, photoelectric-effect

The square law of Fowler for photoemission into a vacuum is based on the assumption that the photoelectron current is proportional to the number of electrons available in the metal **per unit volume** with the velocity component normal to the metal surface.

With this volume assumption Fowler gives the expression for the photoelectron current as:
$$
I \propto \int_{u_0}^{\infty} \ln \left[1+e^{\left(E_{\mathrm{f}}-\frac{1}{2} m u^2\right) / k_{\mathrm{B}} T}\right] \mathrm{d} u
$$

and $E_{\mathrm{f}}$ is the Fermi energy of metal, $\Phi$ the work function of metal, $h v$ the radiation energy, $u$ the velocity of electron perpendicular to the surface, $m$ the mass of electron, $k_{\mathrm{B}}$ Boltzmann's constant.

The expression converted to a function of energy is:

$$
I_{\mathrm{p}} \propto \int_{E_{\mathrm{f}}+\Phi-N_{\mathrm{A}} h \nu}^{\infty} \ln \left[1+e^{\left(E_{\mathrm{f}}-E\right) / R T}\right] E^{-1 / 2} \mathrm{~d} E
$$
where $N_{\mathrm{A}}$ is Avogadro's number.

Now, this [paper](https://www.publish.csiro.au/ch/pdf/ch9750253) suggests that rather than considering the number of available electrons **per unit volume** as proportional to photoelectron current the number of electrons available **per unit surface area**. This may be done by multiplying the integrand in the first expression by $u$.

I do not understand why multiplying by a velocity allows us to consider the surface area rather than the volume process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Matthews & Khan paper](https://www.publish.csiro.au/ch/pdf/ch9750253) says the photoelectric current is proportional to the number of electrons per unit area **per unit time**, which are the correct units if a density per unit volume is multiplied by a velocity.

Photoelectric emission from surfaces is a surface effect, so it makes sense that the photoelectric current (charge per unit time) per unit area will depend on the number of electrons arriving at the surface per unit area per unit time.  The "surface" is the region where light can penetrate and photoelectric electrons can escape without scattering so much that they no longer have enough energy to leave the material.